# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable while extracting from the ditionary

Tags: python

- I am trying to extract the one value from dictionary
- If `value` not present in `parames` key I am passing a default value
- I am getting `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType'`

Below is the dictionary

```
event = {
  'resource': '/test',
  'path': '/test',
  'httpMethod': 'GET',
  'headers': None,
  'multiValueHeaders': None,
  'query': None,
  'parames': None,
  'path': None,
  'Variables': None}
```

My code is below

```
if 'value' in event['parames']:
    if isinstance('value', int)
        val = int(event['parames']['value'][0])
    else:
        val = 10
else:
    val = 10
print(val)
```

My idea,

- check `value` is present in `event`
- if present then `value` is extracted
- In exception condition i will get value=10

Comment: When will `isinstance('value', int)` ever be true?

Comment: in `event['params']['value'][0]` is where the problem is, think about it, `event['params']` is `None`, so you were trying to do `None['value']` which made this error.

Comment: What is `event['parames']['value']` supposed to be if it isn't `None`?

Comment: and also, `if 'value' in event['parames']` have same problem of calling `if 'value` in None`

Comment: 1. When you do `in event['parames']`, Python tries to iterate through it. And in your example `event['parames']` is None. 2. 'value' is a string, not looked up value, so isinstance will always fail. 3. Even if it was looked up value, it would fail because you do [0] and int on it. So it's not int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you do `in event['parames']`, Python tries to iterate through it. And in your example `event['parames']` is None.
2. In your code `'value'` is a string because there are quotes around it, so it won't ever enter the if because `isinstance` will fail. I understand you wanted a key 'value', looking at if contents? But: you access `event['parames']['value'][0]`, so isinstance will still fail.
3. "If value not present in parames key I am passing a default value" - this sounds like a place for `dict.get`.

Python likes the "better ask for forgiveness than for permission", so chepner's code is shorter and clearer, but in case you want to do things manually:

```
tmp = (event['parames'] or {}).get('value')
```

Using a trick with `or`, we will get parames or -if parames is None- empty dict. Thus we fix the (1).

Then we use .get as I suggested in (3). It basically looks up given key in the dict (that's why we needed failsafe empty dict) and if it doesn't find it, it returns a default value (second argument, if not given returns None).

So now our `tmp` is either contents of value or None.

If value is always a list/iterable when it exists, we can do just if check on it:

```
if tmp:
   ...
```

This checks `bool(tmp)` underneath - which is False only for intuitively empty stuff - None, 0, empty iterables/strings (len(something) == 0)...

Since we assumed `tmp` is always an iterable and now we know it's not None and its length is not 0, then we can get our [0].

But it leaves the int stuff. But! We can check strings for numeric values using `str.isnumeric`. But this also assumes we get a string inside and not something else that can be

So full code:

```
tmp = (event['parames'] or {}).get('value')
if tmp and tmp[0].isnumeric():
    val = int(tmp[0])
else:
    val = 10
```

(If you use Python3.8+, you can use walrus operator to declare `tmp` in if.)

So... that's it. But as you can see, we got multiple assumptions here about what parames and value are. That's why chepner's code is better - it doesn't make any assumptions. But since you seemed like you're learning, I decided to post longer code to explain each problem.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
try:
    val = int(event['parames']['value'][0])
except (TypeError, LookupError, ValueError):
    val = 10
```

This will set `val` to `10` if any of the following are true:

0. `event['parames']` raises a `KeyError`
1. `event['parames']['value']` raises a `KeyError` or `TypeError`
2. `event['parames']['value'][0])` raises either a `TypeError`, `KeyError` or `IndexError`
3. `int(event['parames']['value'][0])` raises a `ValueError`.

Comment: updated the code, and can you help in understanding? why its throwing error? can we write in if else loop

Comment: It's throwing an error because the string `'value'` is *never* going to be an instance of `int`, so you end up in the wrong branch.

Answer (score 0):

I got one more solution. if it helps

```
if event.get('parames', False) != False:
    if isinstance('value',int):
        val = 10
else:
    val = 5
print(val)
```